# Identify Outlook Folder is for Sent or received email item

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

is it possible to identify folder is for send or received

```
private void EnumerateFoldersInDefaultStore()
    {
        Folder root =
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.
            DefaultStore.GetRootFolder() as Folder;
        EnumerateFolders(root);
    }


    private void EnumerateFolders(Folder folder)
    {
        Folders childFolders =
            folder.Folders;
        if (childFolders.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Folder childFolder in childFolders)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

have done the above code to enumerate folder list but dont know how to determine folder type

Comment: which Folder Class are you using? [sharepoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee538057(v=office.15)) or [microsoft.exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Comment: sorry , i am not getting .i am not using any Folder Class

Comment: `EnumerateFolders(Folder folder)` whats the type exactly? Full namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are trying to figure out whether a folder in question is one of the default folders? Retrieve the default folder using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` (or `olFolderSentMail`) and compare its entry id with the entry id of your folder using `Namespace.CompareEntryIDs`.

Comment: i think there is no way to identify that this specific folder is only for received or sent email items, because outloook is not restricting user to that this folder only contain sent or received email